# How do I add, accumulate, sum time diff in PHP?

Tags: php, datediff

I am trying to add the differences from php date time objects and I am doing something wrong. I get the time differences I expect:

$total = 00:11:33
$accumulator = 00:05:47

but how do I add the DateIntervals? Or do I just create a new dateTime object and add to it?

```
$total = new DateInterval('P0000-00-00T00:00:00');
$accumulator = new DateInterval('P0000-00-00T00:00:00');
$a = new DateTime('2014-01-05 00:01:38');
$b = new DateTime('2014-01-05 00:13:11');
$c = new DateTime('2014-01-05 00:18:58');
$d = new DateTime('2014-01-05 00:24:45');

$total = $a->diff($b);
$accumulator =  $c->diff($d);

echo '$total = ' . $total->format("%H:%I:%S");
echo '$accumulator = ' . $accumulator->format("%H:%I:%S");

$total += $accumulator;

echo 'Grand Total = ' . $total->format("%H:%I:%S");
```

Comment: You're using `->format()` wrong. It does not use `%` for its format chars, and `I` would correspond to a DST-in-effect flag, not minutes. You want `->format('H:i:s')`. `S` is `2nd/3rd/4th` suffixes as well.. .`s` (lowercase) is seconds.

Comment: Why are you initializing `$total` and `accumulator` with `new DateInterval` when you're just going to replace them with the result of `diff`?

Comment: You can't add `DateInterval` with `+`. It doesn't look like it's possible to add `DateInterval` at all. You can only add them to `DateTime`. I think that's because intervals like month and year depend on where you're starting from, because of different month lengths and leap years.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Barmar, I found the formatting for the DateInterval in the PHP doc here:[link](http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php). I guess I'll use a new date object with the time set to 00:00 and add to it. I only need the total time and it will be less than 23 hours 59 minutes so I guess that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use the Carbon extension.
https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon